# Jackson obectMapperwriteValue() not working as expected

Tags: java, json, jackson

I deserialize the data.json file to Customer.java. And tried to serialize Customer.java to shopping.json. But it is showing two list objects (list and food) in the serialized json data. There should be only one list (i.e., food). What went wrong? Please see the code below:

```
ShoppingList.java
private String name;
private int amount;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ShoppingList [name=" + name + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
}
```

Customer.java

```
private String date;
private String name;
private String store;
@JsonProperty("food")
private List<ShoppingList> food;

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getStore() {
    return store;
}

public void setStore(String store) {
    this.store = store;
}

public List<ShoppingList> getList() {
    return food;
}

public void setList(List<ShoppingList> list) {
    this.food = list;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer [date=" + date + ", name=" + name + ", store=" + store + ", food=" + food + "]";
}
```

Test.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    File file = new File("data.json");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Customer m = mapper.readValue(file, Customer.class);
    System.out.println(m.toString());
    System.out.println(m.getList().toString());

    mapper.writeValue(new File("shopping.json"), m);

}
```

data.json

```
{
"date": "2016-07-14",
"name": "Candice",
"store": "aStore",
"food": [
    {
        "name": "eggs",
        "amount": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "Chicken",
        "amount": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Bananas",
        "amount": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Pasta",
        "amount": 1
    }
]
```

}

shopping.json

```
{
"date": "2016-07-14",
"name": "Candice",
"store": "aStore",
"list": [ //This list is generated extra.
    {
        "name": "eggs",
        "amount": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "Chicken",
        "amount": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Bananas",
        "amount": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Pasta",
        "amount": 1
    }
],
"food": [
    {
        "name": "eggs",
        "amount": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "Chicken",
        "amount": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Bananas",
        "amount": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Pasta",
        "amount": 1
    }
]
```

}

I tried in different ways but no luck. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because you have `getList` and `setList` methods in class `Customer`. Try renaming them to `getFood` and `setFood`. Or put `@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "list" })` on the `Customer` class to make Jackson ignore the `list` property.

Comment: thanks for the answer @jesper. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused for your naming. Rename you `getList` method and `setList` method to `getFood` and `setFood` and try again.